# in typescript env, I create HttpException that derive class of Error, use it at my express error handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, httpbackend

why it can use without new HttpException() then trown a error
I saw this method elsewhere，and it is work

Here is HttpException

```
class HttpException extends Error{
  constructor(public status: number,public message: string){
      super(message);
      this.status=status;
      this.message=message;
  }
}
export default HttpException;
```

Here is error handler

```
const errorMiddleware = (error: HttpException, _request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const status = error.status || 500;
  const message = error.message || ' something wrong';

  response
    .status(status)
    .send({
      status,
      message
    });
    
  logger.error(error.name);
  logger.error(error.message);
  logger.error(error.stack);

  next(error);
};
```

user in app.ts

```
// ...some routers
app.use(errorMiddleware)
```

api error in postman

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "User validation failed: username: Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `aaa111`"
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? The code is nice formatted, but I can't understand what is the problem :-(

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález i not know why it thrown error type is HttpException,not Errro,it is because error that func params type is named HttpException? then throw HttpException type instance？

Comment: Because some calls have custom type errors. Is like when you write bad syntax, like `var var a = 123; (double var)`, you get "SyntaxError".